# Realignment of ContextMenuStrip to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a C# winForm project that displays a ContextMenuStrip when the user clicks on a specific row of my dataGridView it allows the user to enter data into the a toolStripTextBoxItem...the problem I'm having is when I add more controls to my winForm dynamically via a TableLayoutPanel...this causes my dataGridView to re-position but my ContextMenuStrip is "stuck" in it's previous location. How do I attach my ContextMenuStrip to my dataGridView so it re-positions itself with the new position of my dataGridView?

Here's an example of what I have.

```
ContextMenuStrip ctxtMnuStrp = ContextMenuStrip();
ctxtMnuStrp.Closing += ctxtMnuStrp_Closing;

ToolStripTextBox txtBox = new ToolStripTextBox();

ctxtMnuStrp.Items.Add(txtBox);

DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
grid.MouseClick += grid_CellClick;

private void grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = grid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
    ctxtMnuStrp.Show(grid.PointToScreen(new Point(rect.Left, rect.Bottom));
 }

 private void ctxtMnuStrp_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked ||
         e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppFocusChange)
         e.Cancel = true;
 }
```

This works fine as far as initially positioning my ContextMenuStrip and keeping it open while the user interacts with my ContextMenuStrip...but when another dataGridView is add to my winForm it causes my grid to reposition and my ContextMenuStrip doesn't reposition/align itself to the new location of my grid and left hanging in it's initial position.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

-DA

Comment: You've got the wrong tag, mate; you tagged for C, but this is a C# question.  I don't know any C# myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need use sender in handler event function. Something like this:

```
private void grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView source = (DataGridView) sender;
    Rectangle rect = source.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
    ctxtMnuStrp.Show(source.PointToScreen(new Point(rect.Left, rect.Bottom));
}
```

Comment: but this has nothing to do with click. i can align if the user clicks...i'm talking about when widgets are add dynamically and grid is re-positioned if the contextMnuStrip is open it doesn't get re-positioned also

Comment: Do you want want change position of Context Menu while it is opened?

Comment: yes...thats what i trying to do. if the grid is repositioned or resized while the cxtMnuStrip is open the cxtMnuStrip is not being respositioned. it's left hanging in the previous grid location

Comment: I assume you should handle LocationChanged event of the grid or it's container control and move active ContextMenu instance

Comment: thx. i accept this as a valid solution but do you know of anyway i could "attach" it the the appropriate cell. i'm really trying to get away for all of these dataGridView events. seems like there are just too many chained events firing off with dataGridView and it's hurting me performance wise.